Morphing for beginners
I want to make a banana (morph) out of a glass. The transformation must be done using shape keys. Where should I start?



Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

it's not clear what difficulty you've met exactly. I would say create your glass:

Then create your 2 shapekeys, keep the second selected and create your banana shape by moving the edges:

Animate the shapekey Value:

